# use IncludeMultiple in a method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using Ladislav Mrnka's extension method:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> IncludeMultiple<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
        params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
        where T : class
    {
        if (includes != null)
        {
            query = includes.Aggregate(query,
                      (current, include) => current.Include(include));
        }

        return query;
    }
```

I took the following method from [Here](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) (after little change):

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] filters = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = GetQuery();

            if (filters != null)
            {
                foreach (var filter in filters)
                {
                    query = query.Where(filter);
                }
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            return query;
        }
```

I want to use the IncludeMultiple instead of strings in includeProperties variable.
So, I changed the function:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] filters = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = GetQuery();

            if (filters != null)
            {
                foreach (var filter in filters)
                {
                    query = query.Where(filter);
                }
            }

            if (includes.Length > 0)
            {
                query = query.IncludeMultiple(includes);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            return query;
        }
```

Now, I am a little bit confuse. This method defined in a class where GetQuery() is defined (repository implementation). But in case I want to execute this method, I would have initially use GetQuery()..
Am I right?
Is it better to use this as an extension to IQueryable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to use this method after you call `GetQuery` because calling `GetQuery` is the first command in this method. You can use either `GetQuery` or `Get` depending on your needs. The `Get` method is actually very good because it hides including. Using it as a repository method is much better then using it as extension method in case of unit testing and mocking.

Comment: What are the pluses and minuses of puttting the Get method in the repository comparing to putting the Get method as an extension to IQueryable?

Comment: @Naor: Extension method is static - it is once written and you can't change it, you can't mock it. Instance method can be made virtual and overriden in derived classes. Extension method is not part of the class interface and can be used on multiple classes implementing the same type used in `this` declaration of extension method.