# expose Include method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an interfaces for my data tier that supply common methods like insert, update, delete, getQuery.

Sometimes I want to add a method that handles the repository. I noticed that I can do almost everything using those common method that the interface supply. The only thing I cannot do is "Include".

I have doubts whether to add the Include method to the db interfaces so my business tier can do everything without being depend on the entity framework (system.data.entities).

What is the workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a workaround.  Adding `Include` to your DB interfaces (`IObjectSet`) is a common approach to solving this problem.  As far as your concern about being tied too closely to Entity Framework, well, I'd say that switching ORMs completely down the road will be quite a bit of work regardless whether you add this extension method.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Here's a [blog post](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/agile-entity-framework-4-repository-part-5-iobjectset/) from Julie Lerman on adding the `Include` extension method

Comment: @Adam Rackis: Adding include forces the data layer to implement include. Do you really believe I can rely on that Include will be in other or/ms??

Comment: Of course not.  Any ORM you use is going to have specific features it uses—like `Include`.  I think avoiding these features so you can swap in a different ORM down the road is a misplaced priority.  Swapping ORMs is always going to be a nightmare.

Comment: @Adam Rackis: Julie Lerman expose the include method to the data layer. He don't speak about expose it outside.

Comment: She adds it to the IObjectSet interface, which is how your business layer would communicate to your data layer.  From your question that seems to be what you're talking about.  If not, can you supply some more code?

Comment: @Adam Rackis: I can't see where she adds it but I believe you :) Do you know maybe where is the place for common queries for an entity? I mean, I can add class that extends the base repository but that would be a lot of work for one method. This is the reason I was looking to expose Include - so that I can create queries outside of the data tier. But where is the plase for common queries for an entity?

Comment: Well what I do is have my repository interface, which exposes `IObjectSet<Product>`, `IObjectSet<Order>` etc.  Then I have DataAccessObjects take in an instance of my repository, and execute common queries.  So there might be a productDAO that has methods like getProductsOnSale() or getInfrequentlySoldProducts() etc.  It's these methods that would use Include, defined on `IObjectSet<T>` by the extension method in Julie's blog post

Answer (score 3):

Exposing custom `Include` wrapper will not make your upper layers dependent on EF. Include will became part of your DAL layer public interface. Making decisions like "what if I decide to change ORM?" is really bad way to make your application - build working solution and then improve it if you have time do it. Switching to other ORM is really rare and planning your application to support that switch is in 99% cases waste of time and waste of money. Your responsibility is to deliver working solution in time not extensible solution three months later.

The only disadvantage with exposed `Include` can be unit testing and mocking - this requires hiding EF related Includes to DAL internals so that it can be mocked. That is probably solved in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784727/use-includemultiple-in-a-method).

Comment: I am very confused.. I have silly question.. Why am I bothering to do specific tiers and modules with separation of concerns if not for the day I would like to replace one tier?.. Thank you for all your responses.

Comment: @Naor: You are doing it to make your code maintainable. There is still very big difference to write maintainable and modular code. The latter one requires much more effort and very deep upfront analysis.

Comment: Well said Ladislav  +1  To reiterate, writing separate tiers makes you code **testable** and by extension maintainable.